# SAP Connection CPIC hostname unknown

Tags: php, saprfc

I'm creating a connection between SAP system and a web server, this connection is in PHP as well as the libraries for it are for PHP purposes.

I followed every step of this [page](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/EmTech/Compile+sapnwrfc+for+PHP+on+Debian+Linux+%28Lenny%29).

After I got the libraries into my server (nwrfcskd and sapnwrfc) I get this error...

> exception 'sapnwrfcConnectionException' with message ' LOCATION CPIC (TCP/IP) on local host with Unicode ERROR hostname 'afrodita.unimet.edu.ve' unknown TIME Tue Jul 12 02:59:48 2011 RELEASE 711 COMPONENT NI (network interface) VERSION 39 RC -2 MODULE nixxhsl.cpp LINE 233 DETAIL NiHsLGetNodeAddr: hostname cached as unknown COUNTER 7 ' in /var/www/bb/login.php:22 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/bb/login.php(22): sapnwrfc->__construct(Array) #1 {main}

Does anyone has a clue on this matter?

I think that I'm missing some parameters for SAP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that there's no DNS entry for `afrodita.unimet.edu.ve`, so the connection fails. Try using an IP address instead, if you don't have control over the DNS server for unimet.edu.ve.

Comment: just got the dns for afrodita, it doesnt seem to be the problem... :(

Comment: my bad!!!! its solved!!!! it was the DNS settings!!! thanks brou!!! highly appreciated